# Why does a DateTimeFormatter not work if I try to parse time with millis without a fraction

Tags: java

The following code will fail with a DateTimeParseException

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(now);
String s = format.format(now);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, format));
```

whereas the following code will work:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(now);
String s = format.format(now);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, format));
```

The only difference is the "." in the second pattern.

Unfortunately my input data is like the first pattern and I can parse such times with an "old" SimpleDateFormat with the very same pattern.

The question is: why does the new DateTimeFormatter fail here and is there a fix for this?

Comment: The first snippet works too. What Java version are you getting that error on?

Comment: Confirming @ernest_k 's comment: Works with Java 11

Comment: It fails in Java 8.  It seems the easiest solution is to use a more modern Java.

Comment: We currently need to stick on Java 8. But good to know that this problem is fixed with a newer version of Java! Thanks!